# How to integrate Facebook login into Azure Web App

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, oauth, facebook-login

I am trying to connect my **Azure Web App** to a Facebook login.

In the first step I use the [ASP.NET MVC sample from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-dotnet-sqldatabase). The application is up & running after my deployment on all tabs.

[image]

Now I configure my authentication via the Web App settings in Azure. I have already created an application via my Facebook Developers account.

My OAuth Redirect URL is: `https://<app-name>.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/facebook/callback`

[image]

The next time I open the application, the Facebook login page appears and the login works. I can access tabs in my application which are static (like home tab with text content), but I can not open tabs with functionality like "Create New".

Is it necessary to make changes to the code or is it sufficient to change the authentication configuration via the Web App settings in Azure Portal?

[image]

Comment: No you dont have to, can you post the code?

Comment: Find it on GitHub https://github.com/Azure-Samples/dotnet-sqldb-tutorial

Comment: what about the authentication code?

Comment: @Sajeetharan that was my question. I only did the OAuth authentication through azure portal configuration. No code change in the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Startup.Auth.cs you need to add the following piece of code to make sure the

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
appId: "",
appSecret: "");
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/may/cutting-edge-social-authentication-in-asp-net-mvc-4

Comment: Thanks for your help. When creating a new MVC project, the optn "Single user accounts" must be selected for authentication. Then the Startup.Auth.cs is also available. For appId and appSecret then I set the corresponding values from facebook.